# Is it possible for 2 or more PostGIS extensions to coexist?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

When we issue CREATE EXTENSION postgis on our PostgreSQL database, the extension created is the one of which we have the appropriate files of in our PostgreSQL server configuration.

Well, is it possible to create a situation in which we can install both postgis 2.3 and postgis 2.4 extensions for example? Maybe we can't have both extensions active at the same but perhaps we can still switch between 2 versions effortlessly, such as issuing some kind of CREATE EXTENSION postgis2.3 and CREATE EXTENSION postgis2.4 command? I am sure developers could use this to see if a PostGIS feature of a particular version is also functioning the same on another version as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not in the same database, but you can in different databases in the same cluster (Postgres server instance).

What I think you are asking (in same database) is not something we would care to do as it isn't supported in PostgreSQL and even if we could figure out a way, it would be an immense amount of work for little benefit.

To install different versions in same cluster but different dbs, you do these basic steps.

1) Install both PostGIS 2.2 and 2.3 binaries in the cluster.  Note that most packagers usually carry just one version, so you may have to compile yourself depending on OS.

2) Once you have both installed in same cluster,you just need to specify the version number in database.

For PostGIS 2.2 command would be like or whatever version you installed.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis VERSION "2.2.5";
```

For PostGIS 2.3

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis VERSION "2.3.2";
```

Comment: I was more interested on different databases in the same  cluster. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Basic is you install both PostGIS version binaries..  I'll update my answer

Comment: Had no idea that was possible. That's pretty cool! Thanks.

Comment: Now if I am developing my own variation of the extension, which file would I need to change to install it i.e. to perform CREATE EXTENSION postgis VERSION "2.3dev"?

Comment: Nevermind: can answer my own question on this: I just need to modify the control file. Thanks again!